# How to do Wang-Landau sampling when the energy configurations are unknown?

Tags: density-of-states

My question is about estimating the density of states for [boolean formula](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Eermonste/papers/cp2010_counting.pdf). Where the problem is that given a boolean formula $F$, with $n$ variables the energy is a function $E:\{0,1\}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And our goal is to estimate $n(E')$ i.e the number of configurations that share the same energy $E'$.

Now the problem is that in my setup the set of all possible $E$ values is not known before hand, I only have a (not so tight) upper bound. And the sampling should give not only $n(E)$ for all energy values but also, all possible energy values $E$ as well.

The practical repercussion of this problem is that it is almost impossible to know when the histogram is flat as you don't really know all the possible energy states.

Are there similar situations in Physics problems too? If yes then what modifications do they make to deal with such a situation? Also, what is the usual cardinality of the number of such possible energies?

Comment: In Wang-Landau sampling you do not have to have all energies from the start, but only the energies which you visit.  Are you saying you want to find the number of states for given energy without knowing how to calculate energy?

Comment: @Pavlo.B. Thanks for the reply. No,I do know how to calculate energies, but I don’t have all possible energies. If what you are saying is right then how do you check if the histogram is flat without knowing all the energies ? Basically you could have a flat energy histogram for the finite set of energies you have been to.

Comment: From what I see on wiki, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_and_Landau_algorithm, the histogram becomes flatter the longer you run your algorithm. That's kind of the point of the algorithm, to generate a flat histogram through random walk. Wiki also refers to this paper (https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.2803061) on how to scale the entropy update coefficient $f$ better.